# User merge page wording

Tags: bug, user-interface, merge-accounts

On the user merge request page (for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge)), we read (emphasis mine):

> If you have **lost access** to your duplicate account, please click here to fill out the form.

Clicking "here" gives three steps, the second step happens to be

> 2. Edit your other user profile(s) "About Me" to say merge me as well.

If the user has already lost access to the duplicate accounts, how is the user supposed to edit the profiles?